# Como puedo arregla la marca de agua

Tags: html, css

Estoy agregando una marca de agua en el reporte que genera el modulo de odoo que estoy ocupando pero le mensaje que agrego lo pone delante de las letras del reporte y no quiero que se vea asi

Adjunto codigo:

```
<div 
    class="watermark" 
    style="position:absolute;opacity:0.1;font-size:100px;height:100%;text-align:center-index:1000;right:350px;border:0;padding-top:20px;"
>
    <span style="max-width:150px;color:#DEDCDC;">Copia</span>
</div>
```

ese es el código que ocupe parta poder agregar la marca de agua pero la muestra delante de la información del reporte no se si se deba a la etiqueta que puse para el mensaje de copia

adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que tendría que hacer en los estilos para que se vea atras de la información y no pareciera que la esta tapando

Comment: Si estás poniendo un texto con css por delante de una imagen... no hay nada que puedas hacer. Siempre lo estás poniendo por delante. Lo que puedes hacer es bajarle la opacidad para que al menos sea transparente

Comment: de echo la opacidad de tiene de 0.1 y es muy visible

Comment: ¿Probaste asignando el color con [rgba()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgba)?

Comment: no seria asi rgba(#colorqueseagregue)? seria asi?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías aplicarle transparencia a tu texto aplicando la función [**`rgba()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp):

```html
<div style="background-color: black;">
    <span style="max-width:150px;color:#DEDCDC;">Copia</span><br>
    <span style="max-width:150px;color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);">Copia</span><br>
</div>
```

O también podrías hacerlo agregándole 2 dígitos más en el `HEX` del color, de la cual también le aplica transparencia:

```html
<div style="background-color: black;">
    <span style="max-width:150px;color:#DEDCDC;">Copia</span><br>
    <span style="max-width:150px;color:#DEDCDC40;">Copia</span><br>
</div>
```

Comment: intente las respuestas que pusiste y ninguna funciono gracias de todas formas

Comment: De seguro alguno de los estilos del div de arriba está afectándolo. Quita el opacity de paso.

Comment: pues arriba de ese div tengo un div class row y arriba de ese tengo un div con estilos y solo es un magin y un padding

Comment: De seguro otro estilo o clase no le permite. Al final de cada propiedad `color` agrégale la declaración `!important`, quedando así: `color:#DEDCDC40 !important;`

Comment: ok lo intentare asi

Comment: no funciono cambie los estilos y tampoco

Comment: qué estilos tiene la clase `watermark`?

Comment: style="position:absolute;font-size:100px;height:100%;text-align:center-index:1000;right:350px;border:0;padding-top:20px;"
tiene estos el tipo de poscicion que esta centrado y margenes